# Add checked correct answers and uncorrect(unchecked) answers to the database

Tags: php

I have dynamic checkbox and dynamic textbox in JS. Dynamically add attribute 'checked' is working.

Now, How i can add this checked and unchecked checkbox to the database in PHP?

I tried but it isn't working:

```
$Odp_poprawne=count(preg_grep('/^poprawnosc[\d]*/', array_keys($_POST)))+1;

            $liczba = count(preg_grep('/^odp[\d]*/', array_keys($_POST)))+1;

        for ($i=1; $i < $liczba; $i++) {

             //always sanitize your user data

            if (isset($_POST["poprawnosc".$i])) {
              $poprawnosc2 = mysqli_real_escape_string($sqlc,"YES");
            }
            else
            {
              $poprawnosc2 = mysqli_real_escape_string($sqlc,"NO");
            }
             $odpowiedz2 = mysqli_real_escape_string($sqlc,$_POST["odp".$i]);


             $sql_wprowadz_odpowiedz="INSERT INTO odpowiedzi (Tresc_odpowiedzi, Poprawnosc, ID_pytania) VALUES ('$odpowiedz2', $poprawnosc2, '$row[ID_pytania]')";  //dodawanie kolejnych odpowiedzi do bazy

             mysqli_query($sqlc,$sql_wprowadz_odpowiedz);
        }
        echo "<script type='text/javascript'>alert('Pytanie dodano.');</script>";
        header('Refresh: 0;url=edytuj_pytanie.php');
```

I want add all answers and select this correct answers('YES') and uncorrect answers('NO') to the database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$poprawnosc2 needs to be between quotes, so your query should be:

```
 $sql_wprowadz_odpowiedz="INSERT INTO odpowiedzi (Tresc_odpowiedzi, Poprawnosc, ID_pytania) VALUES ('$odpowiedz2', '$poprawnosc2', '$row[ID_pytania]')";  //dodawanie kolejnych odpowiedzi do bazy
```

Just a note: I wouldn't use "Yes" and "No" for that. I would use instead boolean values (0=false, 1=true), so that 0 would mean that the box wasn't checked, 1 that it was.

Comment: @Natalia You're welcome :) Next time you have a similar problem, you can solve it by yourself adding var_dump($yoursqlquery) just after your query and launch the output on phpMyAdmin: if it runs, it means that the problem is in the php code, otherwise it is in the query (and in this case you will be told where the error is by phpMyAdmin) :)

Comment: @Natalia If this solved your issue, why not accept the answer? It's one click ;)